# Set start time in HTML Video going back to 0 instead of value

Tags: javascript, html

I tried both

```
<video id="Video" preload autoplay loop>
    <source src="video.mp4#t=00:00:37" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

and

```
<video id="Video" preload autoplay loop>
    <source src="`+EpisodeURL+`#t=37" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

But nothing works.

I also tried in JS:

```
video.currentTime = 37.0;
```

or

```
video.currentTime = 37;
```

or

```
video.currentTime = "37";
```

or using video.js
and setting the HTTP header Accept Ranges: bytes.

I also tried to use a different video..

No errors in the console, just goes back to 0 seconds.

Nothing works, please help

Comment: Did you tried this one  <source src="video.mp4#t=2" type="video/mp4">, as per the docs #t=[(start_time), (end_time)]

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the whole js code?
Because video.currentTime is  working fine in my system

```
const video=document.getElementById('video')
const setTime=()=>{
    video.currentTime=0.3;

}
button.addEventListener('click',setTime)
```

Comment: I was running it from $ firebase serve (Since I'm working with a firebase app) but now simply opening the HTML file in chrome works. any idea how this could be?